# Groovy MissingPropertyException on final static property

Tags: groovy, properties, static

The exception is I get is:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: EISBN for class: de.hbznrw.ygor.export.structure.TitleStruct
Possible solutions: EISSN, ISSN, PISSN
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeStaticMissingProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1007) at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1862) 
  at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1155) 
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:1838) 
  at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1155) 
  at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getProperty(MetaClassImpl.java:3763) 
  at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.getProperty(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1167) 
  at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(ClassMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:51) ...
```

The code of [TitleStruct](https://github.com/hbz/laser-ygor/blob/master/src/groovy/de/hbznrw/ygor/export/structure/TitleStruct.groovy) is:

```
class TitleStruct {    
    static final ISSN  = 'issn'
    static final EISSN = 'eissn'
    static final PISSN = 'issn'
    static final EISBN = 'isbn'
    static final DOI = 'doi'

    // plus some getters
}
```

Now, isn't this weird? One of these `final static` properties (`EISBN`) is "dismissed", for no reason I can find, while three of the other properties are provided as a solution (`EISSN`, `PISSN` and `ISSN`). Though, there is absolutely no difference in the properties' treatment in the code. (For the investigative ones: project is [here](https://github.com/hbz/laser-ygor)).

Obviously, the fifth property `DOI` is also not provided as a solution. But this is due to bigger spelling differences than the other three properties. I can see that it exists in the debugger. (`EISBN` is **not** visible in the debugger.)

Even more, same code is running on my colleague's computer - and it has been running on my machine before. The Exception occured suddenly. Therefore, I assume the problem to be located in the compiler area.

So, my question is: has anyone ever experienced a similar issue like this? Any suggestions? Thanks a lot, guys!

Comment: and how do you access this property ?

Comment: You have described an abnormal situation, that is not possible to recreate based on the information you provided. What is the full stack trace you get? (So we can see which invocation starts the error chain). What is the exact situation when this error occurs? What is the state of your application when it happens? Try to provide [mcve]. Source code of your application might be helpful, but running it and debugging does not sound like a good option.

Comment: @daggett access is triggered by: `if(!type.equals(TitleStruct.DOI) && !type.equals(TitleStruct.EISBN)) {...}` .

@SzymonStepniak this is also a very minimal code example. It's called when I'm stopping in another class. But the same happens when calling `TitleStruct.EISBN` almost anywhere in my appication (tested with debugger). So it must an "early" compiler problem.

Comment: as soon as it's grails, there is a dynamic incremental compilation of each class. and there is a possibility of such behavior. try to clean and rebuild whole project. do you have this behavior in a war or only in development mode?

Comment: @daggett: It's development mode. I've cleaned the project by `grails clean` and this solved it! Would you mind making your comment be an answer?

The thing was that I had rebuild the project before, but without a clean... shame on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as soon as it's grails, there is a dynamic incremental compilation of each class.

and there is a possibility of such behavior.

try to clean and rebuild whole project.

Comment: Thank you! `grails clean` was the decisive step that I had missed before.